# Running long tasks that cannot be interrupted in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, go, worker

I have a problem that I think must be very common but I'm not finding a solution. 
I have go routines in my Go app in Heroku, which are long (7 minutes), use the app's Redis database, and cannot be interrupted. I saw that the auto scaler sometimes kills the Heroku dyno which is running the task. I need a way of running this task independently from the dynos so I know that it is completed.
I have the exact same problem in my Rails app.

I was mentioned the 'one-off-dynos' and I read a bit about them. 
Is there something similar I could use from my Rails and Go code that can take care of my tasks without interrupting them?
I tried with the delayed jobs worker but maybe this isn't the cleanest thing to do.
What do you recommend I do?

Comment: whenever the box runs out of RAM the OS will kill the offending process ... in the same address space as your process run the command : ` top` or similar during an execution of your process to confirm you still have free space during such a kill event